# I need to split 2 million records in txt file with demiliter and convert into xlsx

Tags: java, performance, xlsx

I need to split 2 million records in txt file with demiliter and convert into xlsx and save it to specified path. I tried `BufferedReader` and `SXSSFWorkbook`, still xls is not generated for huge records.

What is the issue with my code?

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xlsxFilePath));

int i = 0;
int m = 0;
allRowAndColData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
while ((currentLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {

    oneRowData = new ArrayList<String>();

    String oneRowArray[];
    oneRowArray = currentLine.split("\\|");
    String[] oneRowArray1 = new String[oneRowArray.length + 2];
    if (m == 0) {

        oneRowArray1[0] = "Ticket_No";
        oneRowArray1[1] = "Ticket_Notes";

        m++;
    } else {

        oneRowArray1[0] = "";
        oneRowArray1[1] = "";

    }
    System.arraycopy(oneRowArray, 0, oneRowArray1, 2, oneRowArray.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < oneRowArray1.length; j++) {
        oneRowData.add(oneRowArray1[j]);
    }

    allRowAndColData.add(oneRowData);

    System.out.println();
    i++;
}

try {

    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    SXSSFWorkbook wbss = new SXSSFWorkbook(workBook,1);
    Sheet sheet = wbss.createSheet("sheet1");

    for (int z = 0; z < allRowAndColData.size(); z++) {
        ArrayList<?> ardata = (ArrayList<?>) allRowAndColData.get(z);
         Row row = sheet.createRow(0+z);
        for (int k = 0; k < ardata.size(); k++) {

            Cell cell = row.createCell(k);

            if (!isInteger(ardata.get(k).toString())) {
                cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(k).toString());

            } else {
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(ardata.get(k).toString()));

            }


        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\DM29115\\Downloads\\outputFile.xlsx");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wbss.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: XLSX has a limit of 1,048,576 rows

Comment: See limitations and workarounds: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html

Comment: Why do you have two loops? Because of that you have to store all records in the memory. You could have one loop to iterate over txt file and  dump into Excel. And yes XLSX has a limit of 1,048,576 rows per sheet so you might have to have several sheets in Excel file

Comment: Can't you just load it as CSV in Excel?

Comment: `try { ..` .. what's the `catch`? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).